# How can I use CASE on this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
DATE(DTM) AS'Dia',
ROUND(COUNT(TMP)/4) AS 'Oídio'
CASE 
ROUND(COUNT(TMP)/4)>=6 THEN '20'
ROUND(COUNT(TMP)/4)<6 THEN '-10'
END
FROM dados_meteo
WHERE TMP>=20 AND TMP<=30
GROUP BY DATE(DTM)
```

Comment: It's not working with the CASE statement but it works without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for this perhaps?

```
SELECT
DATE(DTM) AS 'Dia',
ROUND(COUNT(TMP)/4) AS 'Oídio',
CASE 
WHEN ROUND(COUNT(TMP)/4)>=6 THEN '20'
WHEN ROUND(COUNT(TMP)/4)<6 THEN '-10'
END
FROM dados_meteo
WHERE TMP>=20 AND TMP<=30
GROUP BY DATE(DTM)
```

You need to use `WHEN` to mark the branches of a `CASE` and you were missing a comma before the `CASE`.